# Warning / Error for syntax with strtotime and date

Tags: php, codeigniter, strtotime

I have just migrated a website to a new host. Not sure what software was used at the previous host, but assuming it was Apache with PHP. I am now using WAMP server( Apache 2.4.4 and PHP 5.4.16 ). The site is built on the Codeigniter framework.

I am getting two errors:

```
    Message: strtotime() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given

    Message: date() expects parameter 2 to be long, string given
```

They report its because of these lines:

```
    <?=date("d.m - H:i", utf8_encode(strtotime($job->DateEnd))); ?>
```

This is not the only line giving this error, there is a total of 151 hits in 37 files just for "strtotime". Am no PHP coder, but this seem to be my last challenge after spending 3 days getting this site back up!

If any other code is needed, tell me and ill try to find it. I just didnt think it would fit to put every line with the search result of "strtotime" and "date" in here.

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

EDIT (after 3 hours, more info) :
I put in the var_dump function right after that other line, and it showed this:

```
    object(DateTime)#23 (3) { ["date"]=> string(19) "2014-01-08 23:59:00"["timezone_type"]=> int(3) ["timezone"]=> string(3) "UTC" }
```

I think I found the code where $job gets set.

```
    function job_info() {

    $project = "";
    $job_arranger = "";
    $project_arranger = "";
    $customer = "";
    $contact = "";
    $delivery_address = "";
    $human_resources = "";
    $vehicle_resources = "";

    $job = $this->job->get_job_data($this->uri->segment(3));
    if($job->IdUser_Arranger){
        $job_arranger = $this->address->get_user_data($job->IdUser_Arranger);   
    }

    if($job->IdProject){
        $project = $this->job->get_project_data($job->IdProject);
    }
    if(is_object($project)) {
        if($project->IdUser_Arranger) {
            $project_arranger = $this->address->get_user_data($project->IdUser_Arranger);           
        }
        if($project->IdAddress_Customer) {
            $customer = $this->address->get_address_data($project->IdAddress_Customer);         
        }
        if($project->IdContact_Customer) {
            $contact = $this->address->get_contact_data($project->IdContact_Customer);
        }
    }
    if($job->IdAddress_Delivery){
        $delivery_address = $this->address->get_address_data($job->IdAddress_Delivery);
    }
    $human_resources = $this->job->get_job_human_resources($this->uri->segment(3));
    $vehicle_resources = $this->job->get_job_vehicle_resources($this->uri->segment(3)); 

    $data['job'] = $job;
    $data['project'] = $project;
    $data['job_arranger'] = $job_arranger;
    $data['project_arranger'] = $project_arranger;
    $data['customer'] = $customer;
    $data['contact'] = $contact;
    $data['delivery_address'] = $delivery_address;
    $data['human_resources'] = $human_resources;
    $data['vehicle_resources'] = $vehicle_resources;
    $this->load->view('jobs/job_info', $data);  



        }   
    }
```

I am a total newbie on PHP, so even finding where $job gets set is hard for me to understand.

I am guessing the error occurs because we changed to a new SQL Datbase Server, and the dates are handled differently?

Comment: Aren't the errors obvious?

Comment: your $job->DateEnd are you sure is a string?

Comment: The message is clear: `$job->DateEnd` is an object of something and not a string. Check what `$job->DateEnd` is for example with `var_dump($job->DateEnd)`.

Comment: Goiku, he sure is not:) The warning says it is an object. 
Can you show us the code where $job gets assigned with data?

Comment: `var_dump($job->DateEnd)`

Comment: It might be obvious for some, but I have almost no experience with PHP. I updated the main post with more info. Hope it explains it?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the data assigned to $job->DateEnd is an object. Either create a function to retrieve the required data from it and return it as a string (this means changing a lot of code on a lot of places) or change the way $job->DateEnd is filled (this means changing a single key piece in your code).

I would opt for the latter and fight the problem at it's source!

Good luck!